# How do I get interval-specific survival rates from an Andersen-Gill model?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am using `coxph` in the survival library to create Andersen-Gill models. I am interested in getting interval-specific survival rates for my data. For instance, I have 26 time intervals and would like to know the probability of survival within each interval. My basic code on a null model is as follows:

```
coxph <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, death.time)~1, data=mydata)
plot(survfit(coxph), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Weeks", ylab="% Mortality")
```

[image]

This model is obviously just a null model for the sake of this example, but is there any way to get interval-specific survival rates, i.e., weekly survival or even just an overall period (26) survival probability?

Comment: Are you asking how such rates can be calculated for a specific interval in general (eg, mathematically), or are you asking for R code? Note that the latter is off topic here.

Comment: I'm asking how such rates can be calculated for the specific time intervals in general. Thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks. It may help some potential answerers if they have access to the actual data (eg for demonstration purposes), although some don't use R. Can you provide it?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_cox_model <- coxph(....)   
sf <- survfit(my_cox_model)
summary(sf)
```

This should give you the actual values of the survival. For more things you can do with that, check out `?survfit.coxph`.

P.S. It is pretty bad practice to name your model `coxph`, since that is already the name of the function `coxph(...)`. I would name it differently.

Answer (score 1):

An "Andersen-Gill model" handles multiple *recurrent* events of the same type with a single baseline hazard function. If your outcome is "death" then it's not really an Andersen-Gill model, as each individual only has one event. See Section 3.2 of the main R [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf).

What you have seems instead to be interval-censored panel data, with death as the outcome. You know that death occurred sometime within the interval, not exactly when. The coding with `(startTime, stopTime, status)` might be the same, but the analysis is different. As Section 2.8.1 of the survival vignette says: "Such data requires further assumptions about the transition process in order to model the outcomes and has a more complex likelihood." The vignette recommends the [`msm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=msm) as an alternative.

With your data having only about two dozen distinct time intervals and your stated interest in interval-specific death probabilities, a discrete-time survival analysis might be simpler. That's essentially a binomial regression model (logistic regression, or with a [complementary log-log link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/429266/28500) if you have proportional hazards) that treats time as a fixed effect. Then you can just get predictions for any particular time period directly by specifying the time and covariate values of interest.